# CMake or gyp for node.js addon development

Tags: node.js, cmake, add-on, gyp

In most of tutorials, they use gyp as the building system for C++ node.js add-on development. However, compared to gyp, CMake has a long history and have much much more documentations.

Therefore, my question is that: which one is better for node.js C++ addon development?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan and dont try to develop your add-on from scartch as they are likely to become out of date with the nodejs runtime

Answer (score 13):

I've just made available my new module today: [CMake.js](https://github.com/unbornchikken/cmake-js) to support CMake based Node.js and io.js native addon development. It works exactly like node-gyp, please take a look at the readme and to the tutorial, then decide what's better for you.

Comment: I created a tutorial that shows how to use Qt Creator to create and debug CMake.js based native node addons: https://github.com/unbornchikken/cmake-js/wiki/TUTORIAL-02-Creating-CMake.js-based-native-addons-with-QT-Creator

Comment: Does it get integrated into a regular workflow (like integrating the addon as part of a regular cmake project)?

Comment: @GopalakrishnaPalem this is my main problem with Cmake.js. I want to ship my NodeJs binding of my massive CMake based C++ project. With CMake.js you seem to call the cmake.js script which will call your cmake binary with some variables populated for linking nan, etc. Really, a find or config module for cmake would prevent me from telling every user of my project to create project files with cmake.js...

Comment: It was designed to cover the regular npm+nodegyp workflow, with an ability to use CMake based projects as dependencies and features of CMake itself. If you want to ship anything to a node guy, he will give a pile of stinking crop on your huge makefiles and install instructions. He would like to see an npm module which is an "npm install" away. That's CMake.js job.

Answer (score 1):

gyp is really the only one that is supported and is what almost everyone in the node community uses. Also, both v8 and node use it.