# Is there any way to link c++ libraries to node.js using make not .gyp?

Tags: c++, c, node.js, makefile, add-on

I have c++ libraries that I would like to use with node.js, but I do not want to create a completely new make system using .gyp if my existing make system will work. (I am using 'make; in conjunction with gcc.) Is there anyway to retrofit my make system to produce node.js compatible binaries?

Comment: The first google result for `c++ node.js`: http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/

Comment: I'm assuming this is not something you're going to make public on npm? Also, creating a `binding.gyp` is not difficult. You're already going to have to write some glue code between node and your C++ libraries. If it's the glue code you're trying to avoid, there's [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) but it's slower than glue code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake or gyp for node.js addon development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354876/cmake-or-gyp-for-node-js-addon-development)